# How to place VM virtually besides host in network

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine

I have written a program that simulates a simple machine. This program has its own MAC and uses raw sockets to write raw ethernet frames, effectively managing IP/ARP-Tables etc. on its own.
It is possible communicating with the outside world, but I have problems with the host-to-guest and guest-to-host connection.
At the moment I use a MacVLan interface in *bridge mode*, but the packets destined to the host never arrive in either of the virtual *macvlan1* or the underlying *eth0*. Also my switches dont support the *hairpin* feature required for the *vepa mode*.

I tried reproducing [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1204229/bridge-virtual-interface-into-physical-network) where a user had a similar problem, but firstly the answer did not work for me and secondly the user answering finished with

> It would have been much easier with a macvlan, though..,

So how would I setup a macvlan so that the guest can communicate with the outside world *and* the host?

I would also use bridging (as in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/828993/adding-virtual-interfaces-not-vlan-in-linux)) if it would work for me. (Also I would want to avoid predefining static IPs)

Comment: Just to clarify: You run your program that uses raw sockets in a separate network namespace, and you've configured a macvlan inside this namespace which has an eth0 master in the main namespace, and you've enabled forwarding/routing so your packets properly enter the macvlan interface? I've never tried to use raw sockets myself, and I'm not entirely sure about the details of how they work; in your place I'd have used a `tap` interface (which is then easy to bridge).

Comment: I dont know about the namespaces, but baiscally yes. The forwarding happens automatically by the kernel.
I tried using a TAP interface with bridging. The "VM" received all packets, but all packets it wrote into the TAP somehow vanished. How would you properly bridge the TAP interface?

Comment: If you haven't put it in a namespace, the macvlan is basically useless. "Forwarding happens automatically by the kernel" is exactly the problematic point: At which place do they get injected? If I understand it correctly, raw/packet sockets are basically meant for new IP protocols, not for simulating machines with their own network hardware. That's why e.g. QEMU has tap interfaces. You bridge a tap interface just like any other interface: `ip link set tap0 master br0` etc.And use `tcpdump -ni tap0` to verify if the packets "somehow vanish".

Comment: Also, there's plenty of example programs with working tun/tap implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had to play around with raw sockets now.

However, *raw sockets* (`man 7 raw`, `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, ...)`) really work on layer 3. You said you write raw ethernet frames, and do ARP, so possibly you mean *packet sockets* (`man 7 packet`, `socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ...)`).

For both packet sockets and raw sockets, the packets are not properly routed, but placed directly in the outbound part of a particular interface. This interface can be determined by either binding to it by name, or by looking up the destination address. So "the forwarding happens automatically by the kernel" is not true: No forwarding happens at all. In particular, if the destination is a local address, the packet isn't re-routed through the loopback interface.

This makes this method totally unsuitable for simulating a device with an "extra interface endpoint" into the host.

As for macvlans, bridge mode is described as

> The macvlan is a trivial bridge that doesn't need to do learning as it
>   knows every mac address it can receive, so it doesn't need to implement
>   learning or stp. Which makes it simple stupid and and fast.

I take this to mean that macvlans do bridging by examining the MAC address of the original interface and each additional MAC address added by a macvlan. Which means that as you are emulating the MAC address through raw sockets, the macvlan code doesn't know there's an "additional" MAC address, and so it can't find any destination for it.

Add to that that raw and packet sockets need root (which shouldn't be necessary for an application emulating some other device), then in my opinion, raw and packet sockets are totally unsuitable for this kind of application. They are geared toward implementing new IP protocols or other low-level network stuff in user-space, and nothing else.

So my advice would still be: Don't use raw/packet sockets. Use a tap interface, like QEMU or other emulators do. This will allow your application to run as non-root, and you'll be able to setup any network configuration in the host you like (route it on layer 3, or bridge it on layer 2).

Comment: I did not know that no routing is done when using packet sockets. About the MacVLan: The virtual device uses the exact MAC that is listed in the MacVLan by an ioctl-command. I am not sure how to put raw packets onto a tap, but this question would be off-topic here. Thanks.

Comment: I am still not entirely sure where raw packets are injected, but since they seem to bypass most of the kernel's normal routing code, it's entirely possible they also ignore the macvlan bridging code, and go straight to the outbound queue of the associated interface. And conversely, inbound packets caught by the raw/packet socket hooks may never also see the macvlan bridging code. I guess one would have to check the kernel source to be sure (and I'm too lazy to do that right now).